# Organizing DataFrame Columns into MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to organize the columns of my data frame into groups. Generally when I'm doing analysis I might have something like identifier variables, independent variables and dependent variables and I think it's nice organizationally to put all such variables together under common headings.

Here's an example

```
import string
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": list(string.ascii_lowercase[:5]),
               "b" : np.arange(0,5), 
               "c":list(string.ascii_uppercase[:5]), 
               "d" : np.arange(5,10)})
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["Letter"], ["a","c"]])
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["Number"], ["b", "d"]])
index = index1.union(index2)
df.columns = index
```

This doesn't exactly work.

```
    Letter  Number
    a   c   b   d
0   a   0   A   5
1   b   1   B   6
2   c   2   C   7
3   d   3   D   8
4   e   4   E   9
```

Instead I need to add

```
  df = df[index.get_level_values(1)]
  df.columns = index
```

to rearrange the columns so that they line up with the second level multiindex before I change the index. This feels a bit clunky and I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

Comment: `df = df[index.get_level_values(1)]` seems bugged ?

Comment: I don't know about bugged... maybe just unnecessary. I'm just looking for a clean syntax to group columns together and add a multi index. Even ```pd.MultiIndex.from_product``` seems clunky. I have to create a multi index for each group of columns. I just want to specify a partition of the columns and keys for each partition and get back a hierarchical dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution:

```
import string
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": list(string.ascii_lowercase[:5]),
               "b" : np.arange(0,5), 
               "c":list(string.ascii_uppercase[:5]), 
               "d" : np.arange(5,10)})
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["Letter"], ["a","c"]])
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["Number"], ["b", "d"]])
index = index1.union(index2)
df.columns = index

print(df)
  Letter    Number   
       a  c      b  d
0      a  0      A  5
1      b  1      B  6
2      c  2      C  7
3      d  3      D  8
4      e  4      E  9
```

A more pythonic way of flattening multiindex columns

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print(df)
```

output:

```
Letter_a  Letter_c Number_b  Number_d
0        a         0        A         5
1        b         1        B         6
2        c         2        C         7
3        d         3        D         8
4        e         4        E         9
```